# set div elements position with css

Tags: css, css-position

i have 2 divs . which are div1 and div2 .

my div1 has the below style attributes :

```
.div1{
position:absolute;
left:0%;
top:0%;
width:auto;
height:auto;
}
```

and my div2 :

```
.div1{
position:absolute;
left:0%;
top:0%;
width:auto;
height:auto;
}
```

I want to set my second div to be exactly under my div1 and whenever my div1's height or width changes , my div2 will be also change and still be exactly under the div1 .

please help .

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with [tag:asp-classic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `div2` to be under `div1` then `position: relative` should do it. If you want `div2` to emulate the elements of `div1`, in this case if the width of `div1` increases and you want the width of `div2` to increase, I would make a parent div (in this case `mainDiv`) that encompasses `div1` and `div2`. Following the example from  @Siyam Kumar. Here is what I came up with:

HTML:

```
       <div class="mainDiv">
            <div class=div1>
                <p>this is Div 1 content</p>
            </div>
            <div class=div2>
                <p>this is Div 2 content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.mainDiv{
        padding:50px;
        width: 30px; <!-- you control both div1 and div2 here -->
    }

    .div1{
        position:absolute;
        left:0%;
        top:0%;
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
    }

    .div1{
        position:relative;
        left:0%;
        top:0%;
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        background-color:#AAA;
    }
```

So control you divs using `mainDiv`. So if you change the height, then all the divs will adjust to the assigned height in `mainDiv`.

Answer (score 1):

Set div2 position as relative.

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">adsf</div>
<div class="div2">adfad</div>
```

CSS:

```
div1{
position:absolute;
left:0%;
top:0%;
width:auto;
height:auto;

}
.div2{
position:relative;
left:0%;
top:0%;
width:auto;
height:auto;
background-color:#AAA;
}
```

Comment: Add example, it's better to be understood :)

Answer (score 1):

if you really need position absolute, wrap both div's into a container div with position absolute and then change both div1 and div2 to position relative. that should work